# How to join sections in craft entry query

Tags: entry, query, join

I want to join sections `foo` and `bar` in a `craft entry query`.
Where `foo.id` = `bar.title`.

How do I query all records in one go in style like `craft.entries.section...`?

Comment: Please post your existing code, describe what's not working about it and what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.